# Mysql time calculation with join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:   sales, actions

Sales table:

```
id, datetime, status
--------------------
```

Actions table:

```
id, datetime, sales_id, action
------------------------------
```

There's a many-to-one relations ship between the actions and sales tables. For each sales record, there could be numerous actions. I am trying to determine, by each hour of the day, what the average time difference is between when sales records are first created, and when the first action record associated with it's respective sales record was created.

In other words, how fast (in hours) are sales agents responding to leads, based on what hour of the day the lead came in.

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT

FROM_UNIXTIME(sales.datetime, '%H') as Hour,
count(actions.id) AS actions,
(MIN(actions.datetime) - sales.datetime) / 3600 as Lag

FROM
actions 
INNER JOIN sales ON actions.sales_id = sales.id

group by Hour
```

I get what looks like reasonable hours numbers for 'Lag', but I am not convinced they're  accurate:

```
   Hour Actions Lag
    00  66      11.0442
    01  30      11.2758
    02  50      8.2900
    03  25      5.7492
    .
    .
    .
    23  77      34.4744
```

My question is, is this the correct way to get the values for the first action that was recorded for a given sales record?  :

```
(MIN(actions.createDate) - sales.createDate) / 3600 as Lag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query has two layers, and it's helpful to crawl through them both.

The lowest layer should compute the lag time from `sales.datetime` to the earliest `action.datetime` for each row of `sales.` That will probably use a `MIN()` function.

The next layer will compute the statistics for those lag times, worked out in the lowest layer, by hour of the day. That will use an `AVG()` function.

Here's the lowest layer:

```
 SELECT s.id, s.datetime, s.status,
        TIMEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(a.datetime), s.datetime) AS lag_seconds
   FROM sales AS s
   JOIN actions AS a ON s.id = a.sales_id AND a.datetime > s.datetime
  GROUP BY s.id, s.datetime, s.status
```

The second part of that `ON` clause makes sure that you only consider actions taken after the sales order was entered. It may be unnecessary, but I thought I'd throw it in.

Here's the second layer.

```
 SELECT HOUR(datetime) AS hour_Sale_entered, 
        COUNT(*) AS number_in_that_hour,
        AVG(lag_seconds) / 3600.0 AS Lag_to_first_action
   FROM (
          SELECT s.id, s.datetime, s.status,
                TIMEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(a.datetime), s.datetime) AS lag_seconds
           FROM sales AS s
           JOIN actions AS a ON s.id = a.sales_id AND a.datetime > s.datetime
          GROUP BY s.id, s.datetime, s.status
        ) AS d
  GROUP BY HOUR(datetime)
  ORDER BY HOUR(datetime)
```

See how there are two nested aggregations (`GROUP BY`) operations?  The inner one identifies the first action, and the second one does the hourly averaging.

One more tidbit. If you want to include `sales` items that have not yet been acted on, you can do this:

```
 SELECT HOUR(datetime) AS hour_Sale_entered, 
        COUNT(*) AS number_in_that_hour,
        SUM(no_action) AS not_acted_upon_yet,
        AVG(lag_seconds) / 3600.0 AS Lag_to_first_action
   FROM (
          SELECT s.id, s.datetime, s.status,
                TIMEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(a.datetime), s.datetime) AS lag_seconds,
                IFNULL(a.id,1,0) AS no_action
           FROM sales AS s
           LEFT JOIN actions AS a ON s.id = a.sales_id AND a.datetime > s.datetime
          GROUP BY s.id, s.datetime, s.status
        ) AS d
  GROUP BY HOUR(datetime)
  ORDER BY HOUR(datetime)
```

The average of lag_seconds will still be correct, because the `sales` rows with no `action` rows will have NULL values for that, and `AVG()` ignores nulls.

Comment: So there are syntax errors throughout here, and I am not able to make this solution work.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. It's hard to debug query code without data. Do the principles in have presented help you understand how to approach your problem?

Comment: Conceptually, this is the best answer, as a nested select is required.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
MIN(actions.datetime - sales.datetime) / 3600 AS Lag
```

You way is getting the first action from *any* sale within the hour, and subtracting each sale's timestamp from its timestamp. You need to do the subtraction only within actions and sales that are joined by the ID.

Comment: This returns the lowest lag. How do I get the average of all the lags?

Comment: Use AVG instead of MIN

Comment: AVG does't work. If the range (of lag hours) is 8-60, MIN returns 8, AVG returns 98, MAX returns 1090. The actual average is about 12 hours. I need the 'average' of the 'minimums'.